# Android, ListActivity and subviews

Tags: android, android-activity, subview, listactivity

I have a `ListActivity` which displays a `ListView`. I'm starting the activity from my main activity, and I'd like for the list view to appear as a subview in the view of my main activity. How do I do this?

(It's enough to answer the more general question - how do you bind an activity to a subview in the content view of another activity?)

Comment: Well, there is a nice Tutorial about doing that have a look at it. [ListActivity and ListView](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#overview_listview)

Comment: I have a ListView in my main layout, and it has an id. I'd like to bind that id as the content view of the list activity, i.e. I'd like the list activity to render it's content in the list view of my main layout.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Just set the id to be android:id="@android:id/list". I'll provide an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the id of your ListView to andriud:id="@android:id/list". See the Javadoc for [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html):

> [Y]ou can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

Comment: Thanks. Alternatively, I could dispense with the second activity, and in my main activity create a new `ListAdapter` and set it as the ListAdapter of my ListView in my main layout?

Comment: It depends if you want to visualize these two things as separate screens. If you want two separate screens, then you want two separate Activities. If you just want a single screen with a bunch of stuff, including a ListView, you can use a ListActivity and set the id of the ListView as I describe above.